# JS - Canvas - draw at two canvases simultaneous - ?feed two vars?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, canvas, svg

Got a question. As a rookie I've found a nice script and rewrote it to my satisfaction. But I wonder if I can make the following more memory/performance efficient.

First of all a bit of background.

- I've made a canvas on which I draw a line with the mouse input. Pretty basic.
- With "canvas2svg" I was able to carbon copy the canvas to an svg output/download.

**The question:**

Now, this is all working. But I was wondering if I can make the following piece of code more memory/performance efficient.

the "ctx" var draws on the canvas
the "rttSvg" var draws to the svg file.

```
    points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[points.length - 2].x, points[points.length - 2].y);
    ctx.lineTo(points[points.length - 1].x, points[points.length - 1].y);
    ctx.stroke();

    rttSvg.beginPath();
    rttSvg.moveTo(points[points.length - 2].x, points[points.length - 2].y);
    rttSvg.lineTo(points[points.length - 1].x, points[points.length - 1].y);
    rttSvg.stroke();
```

Can I combine this maybe? Something like this? (rookie waring ahead :)

```
  (ctx.rttSvg).beginPath();
```

**Thoughts**
For a small piece like this I can of course create a function, pass both vars and execute. But than I'll have to make many, many functions, since than I'll have to do this for all the code that interacts with the canvas and svg. And I would like to do this inline.

As you can see, I still have to wrap my head around the JS thinking process. :)

Comment: no, it's not practical to simplify that without wrapping each drawing operation so that it does both

Comment: I disagree.  If the two drawing operations are completely identical then you could simply have a function that takes a context as a parameter and then draws on that context.  Call the function twice...  `function drawStuff(context) {}` and... `drawStuff(ctx);` `drawStuff(rttSvg);`

Comment: @Archer, Ah yes. this does work :)

        points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
 drawStuff(ctx,points); 
        drawStuff(rttSvg,points);

And

        function drawStuff(context,points) { }

Comment: You can take it further than that and not pass `points` as that would be available as long as the function is within the same scope.  I've added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context it's difficult to be 100% sure if this is a valid approach, but you could wrap the drawing within a function and just call that function taking the drawing context as a parameter...

```
function drawStuff(context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(points[points.length - 2].x, points[points.length - 2].y);
    context.lineTo(points[points.length - 1].x, points[points.length - 1].y);
    context.stroke();
}
```

then where appropriate...

```
points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

drawStuff(ctx);
drawStuff(rttSvg);
```

Comment: Ah yes, it works perfect without passing the 'points'. Many thanks!
(I would like to upvote it, but since I have a brandnew account I'll have to wait :)  )

Comment: I'm happy to have helped.  Good luck :)